# How do I stop a Windows::Forms::Dialog resizing in one direction?

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli, resize

I have a dialog box which I programatically alter the height of. The problem now is that I'd like to allow the user to expand it horizontally if they want to see more information.

How can I stop the dialog from resizeing vertically if I allow the user to resize it?

Comment: Refer the following link for the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666788/winforms-how-to-prevent-vertically-resize-in-vb-net

Answer (score 1):

You can set MinimumSize to current size and MaximumSize to, well, maximum size, with height equal as in MinimumSize, and width=800 (or some other really big number).